# Scala 2.13 what to use instead of MutableList?

Tags: scala, scala-collections, mutablelist, scala-2.13

I'm upgrading a software from Scala 2.12.8 to Scala 2.13, and figure out that the collection MutableList (scala.collection.mutable.MutableList) was removed according to many guides (like [this one](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/collections-migration-213.html)).

This guide, for example, say that this was a deprecated collection so that's why it was removed, but I cannot find any deprecation in that class in previous versions.

> "Deprecated collections were removed (MutableList, immutable.Stack, others)"

I also upgrade first to 2.12.9 (latest before 2.13.0) to check it there was any deprecated annotation giving a suggestion on what to use instead, but also in this version the collection is not deprecated.

I searched for this question I couldn't find a good answer.
This question is gonna be good for me and also for future upgrades.

What should I use instead of MutableList, in Scala 2.13 ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/collections-migration-213.html:

> `collection.mutable.MutableList` was not deprecated in 2.12 but was
>   considered to be an implementation detail for implementing other
>   collections. Use an `ArrayDeque` instead, or a `List` and a `var`.

```
scala> val dq = new ArrayDeque[Int]
dq: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayDeque[Int] = ArrayDeque()

scala> dq.append(1)
res1: dq.type = ArrayDeque(1)

scala> dq.append(2)
res2: dq.type = ArrayDeque(1, 2)

scala> dq
res3: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayDeque[Int] = ArrayDeque(1, 2)
```